# Mixed effects Model in Prism versus lmer in R - Post-Hoc testing

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, post-hoc

I am a beginner R user and admittedly only have relatively basic statistics knowledge. But I am keen to learn

I have a patient data set in 2 groups (n = 50; group 1, n = 35, group 2, n = 15), who were measured for 'C' at 6 time intervals (0 = 0 months, 3 = 3 months and so on), every 3 months. The time measurement is not continuous - rather samples collected +/- a month of 3 months are included into the 3 month time point for example. I am primarily interested in determining if there is a difference in 'C' at each time point between the two groups. But I have been asked to also determine if there is an interaction between Group and Time. However, I'm unsure of the type of post-HOC testing I can do.

Due to the nature of patient data collection, I have a few data points missing and so was advised to do a mixed-effects model for my data rather than a repeated measures two-way ANOVA.

I did this on both Prism and using lmer in R. Both programmes show me that there is no interaction between Group and Time although both have a significant effect on the measurement of 'C' independent of each other. Both give me the same predicted mean values for each group at each time point.

I then wanted to determine the differences in 'C' at each time point between the two groups. On Prism, this can be done easily by doing multiple comparisons with Sidak or FDR p-value adjusment when running the mixed-effects model. Prism uses the observed mean values between the two groups to do this.

With lmer, I used the emmeans package to determine differences between the two groups at each time point. But this uses the estimated marginal means rather than the observed values and so the determined p-values seem to be affected by the amount of missing data points at each time point.

Is it incorrect to do a multiple comparison test using the observed group means rather than the estimated marginal means after I've done lmer?

The purpose of the lmer was to determine if there was an interaction between Group and time and since this doesn't exist, can I proceed to use either paired t-test or one-way ANOVA to determine differences in 'C' between groups across time?

Also, is there a way to do "Šídák's multiple comparisons test" on R?