# Time as a factor or numeric in lme4?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, categorical-data, lme4-nlme

I have explained my study design in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/613019/mixed-effects-model-in-prism-versus-lmer-in-r-post-hoc-testing).

To summarize, I have repeated measures data of 2 patient groups for 'C' across 6 different time points. Time measurement is more of a time window - samples collected +/- a month of 3 months are included into the 3 month time point for example.

Below is my current model:

```
model <- lmer(C ~ Group + Time + Group*Time + (1|Sample_ID), REML = TRUE, data = data)
```

I've been playing around with my model set up using `lme4` and I noticed that the interaction between my group (a factor variable of positive or negative) changes when it's coding is changed. For example, time is shown as not significant when Time is a factor, and Time is significant when it is numeric. Why is that?

I do have the exact time measurements available for all my samples and can plug this into my model instead, but I really want to be looking at whether there is a difference between my two groups at each time interval. If I treat Time as numeric and then plug it into my model, my `emmeans` contrasts will only determine a single p-value for patient Group:Time.

Comment: To close voters: respectfully, I do not believe this question is a programming request, as it asks specifically about how to interpret a regression when treated as a factor variable versus a continuous variable. This is a statistical inference question more than it is a data/programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have a time variable $t$ such as the one below, with ten time points:

$$
t = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
$$

If we estimate this as a continuous variable, the regression will fit all estimated values under a single coefficient. If we include it as a factor, it effectively splits up the predictions, in turn giving you a unique coefficient for each individual time. This will naturally change the significance of the coefficients in regressions. As an example with some simulated data below, I have created a 10-point time predictor and a normally distributed outcome variable $y$. Then I fit the data with $t$ as numeric data:

```
#### Sim Data ####
set.seed(123)
t <- rep(seq(1:10),10)
y <- t*.01 + rnorm(n=100, sd = .1)

#### Fit Numeric Regression ####
fit.c <- lm(y ~ t)
summary(fit.c)
```

The summary of the regression looks like this:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ t)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.234666 -0.059717 -0.001804  0.058016  0.210123 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.000725   0.019797   0.037 0.970861    
t           0.011512   0.003191   3.608 0.000488 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.09164 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1173,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1083 
F-statistic: 13.02 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.0004877
```

You can see when I have created a minor association with $t$ and $y$, the coefficient is significant. However, if I fit that same data as a factor:

```
#### Fit Factor Regression ####
fit.f <- lm(y ~ factor(t))
summary(fit.f)
```

The summary now has 10 coefficients, each with their own significance value:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ factor(t))

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.208248 -0.064316  0.002569  0.065867  0.195329 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.01469    0.02946   0.499   0.6193  
factor(t)2  -0.01966    0.04166  -0.472   0.6380  
factor(t)3   0.02592    0.04166   0.622   0.5353  
factor(t)4   0.04688    0.04166   1.125   0.2634  
factor(t)5   0.03664    0.04166   0.879   0.3815  
factor(t)6   0.08489    0.04166   2.038   0.0445 *
factor(t)7   0.09378    0.04166   2.251   0.0268 *
factor(t)8   0.04309    0.04166   1.034   0.3037  
factor(t)9   0.07547    0.04166   1.812   0.0734 .
factor(t)10  0.10652    0.04166   2.557   0.0122 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.09315 on 90 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1624,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.07865 
F-statistic: 1.939 on 9 and 90 DF,  p-value: 0.05615
```

Because this is a categorical regression, it is only comparing each time point to the original reference criterion of Time 1. If we plot the data and draw the regression line based off the continuous fit:

[image]

You can see that this specific regression is predicting an overall single upward trend. However, because the categorical regression is comparing each time point individually to the reference criterion (Time 1), only the time points which are greatly different from it are flagged as significant. You can see for example why Time 10 is significant because it's data points are on average greater than Time 1, whereas Time 3 has generally the same distribution of data as Time 1, thus it is non-significant.

On that note, it should be clear what you are doing with the data in this case. If you are just interested in fitting longitudinal data over a limited number of times of special interest, then fitting them as factors would be preferred, because then you could explain which time points had an actual effect on the response. However, if you have several time points and only want to know what the general trend is, it would be better to fit the data as numeric. Keep in mind there is more to read on this topic, but that would be my advice.

One last thing...you may have noticed my data in particular was somewhat nonlinear. This is relatively common with time-based data. I would check to see that your regression isn't fitting a linear trend to a nonlinear one. If it is, you may need to consider nonlinear methods if you do in fact treat the data as numeric.

Comment: Thank you Shawn! I understand things better now. But to clarify, I am interested in determining if there is an interaction between my Group and Time (the Group * Time part of my model) with C as my dependent variable. The interaction is significant when I code Time as continuous but not significant when I code it as a factor. Both Group and Time (as factor or as numeric) are significant fixed effects for 'C' independent of each other. My issue is that if I keep Time as numeric then I don't know how to look at contrasts of Group against each time point

Comment: If that's the case, you shouldn't code it as numeric unless you want an indirect, general approximation of time by group. The main issue I see here is interpretation. You will need to find a way to explain why specific time points have the interactions that they do, as there will be many coefficients in this case.